# iPad autofills incorrect information

Tags: ipad

Why does my iPad think I am in another state? When I go to Maps, it shows the correct location. When I want to order something off the internet, it autofills Oregon and I am in California. I did buy a refurbished iPad. Is there a setting I am not finding?

Comment: If you are using auto-fill and it is filling in information that is not yours, it sounds like the iPad was not set up as new when you purchased it. Was it Apple refurbished?

Answer (score 1):

AutoFill data is unrelated to your physical location as it's just stored addresses, phone numbers, etc.

You can adjust or remove AutoFill data under Settings > Safari > AutoFill. Generally it's from a contact card that you have selected as yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your location data.

System Preference > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy.

Comment: Per the OP, Maps shows them in the correct location, so location tracking is not the issue. The reset you mentioned only clears [permissions for apps to use location](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033) (i.e. it removes all apps from Settings > Privacy > Location Services and they have to request permission again).